# Chainable Object Methods

Tags: javascript, object, methods, chain

I am a bit lost with this. I know for a fact that I need to assign this to another variable(ex: var that) in order for the methods to be chain-able. Without modifying modifyFunction, who would I be able to make this chainable? 
If any of you can figure this out, then can you explain it to me?

```
function modifyFunction(f) {
   console.log(f);
   return function() {
       var returnValue = f.apply(this, arguments);

       if (returnValue == undefined) {
           return this;
       } else {
           return returnValue;
       }
   };
}

function modifyMethod(o, m) {
   if (o.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
       console.log(o[m] instanceof Function);
       if (o[m] instanceof Function) {
           if (m == "add") {
               modifyFunction(this.o[m]);
           }
           console.log(this.o[m]);
           modifyFunction(o[m]);
           return this;
       }
   } else {
       return this
   }
}


var o = {
   num: 0,
   add: function(x) {
       return this.num += x;
   },
   sub: function(x) {
       return this.num -= x;
   }
};

// We can't chain object o's method because they don't return "this"
//o.add(4).sub(2); // fail - the methods aren't chainable yet!

// Make the add method chainable.
modifyMethod(o, "add");

// Now we can chain the add methods
o.add(2).add(4);
console.log(o.num); // o.num = 6

// Now make the sub method chainable
modifyMethod(o, "sub");

// Now we can chain both the sub and add methods
o.sub(1).add(3).sub(5);
console.log(o.num); // o.num = 3
```

Comment: ONLY modifying the modifyMethod function :)

Answer (score 0):

You can return the instance to the whole `this` object in every function in order to make it chainable:

```js
var o = {
  num: 0,
  add: function(x) {
    this.num += x;
    return this;
  },
  sub: function(x) {
    this.num -= x;
    return this;
  },
  square: function() {
    this.num = this.num * this.num;
    return this;
  }
};

document.body.innerText = o.add(5).sub(2).add(4).square().num;
```

However, you will have to extract the last value by accessing `.num` or by calling a special function like `value()`.

Comment: Just modifying modifyMethod.. Nothing else

Comment: @CodingBear15 The original question contains "Without modifying modifyFunction". Do you want to make it work only by editing `modifyFunction`?

Comment: My bad, I meant to say only modifying the modifyMethod function.